# Why does this test on a selector (reselect library) fail?

Tags: automated-tests, jestjs, reselect

As per the title of the question.

> .../selector.js

```
const makeSelectUserData = () => createSelector(
  selectProfile,
  (profileState) => profileState.get('userData')
);
```

> .../tests/selectors.test.js

```
it('should select the current user', () => {
    const mockedState = fromJS({
      profile: {
        userData: {
          firstName: "X",
          lastName: "Y",
          gender: "Male",
          email: "a@b.cd",
        },
      },
    });
    console.log(userDataSelector(mockedState));
    expect(userDataSelector(mockedState)).toEqual(user);
  });
```

> console.log ... prints:

```
Map { "firstName": "X", "lastName": "Y", "gender": "Male", "email": "a@b.cd" }
```

hence why, but I don't get why other selector **where user is a string (for example) just work and the selector** returns a string as it should.

Strangely enough, the **selector actually behaves correctly**, but the test doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

All that was necessary was to chance expect(...

to

```
expect(userDataSelector(mockedState).toJS()).toEqual(user);
```

since f**romJS() transforms an object to an immutable which is still returned as such by the selector**.

The other tests with **native (primitive) values** still worked because **immutable doesn't alter them**